# Buttons going behind external swf in as2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, loader, key-events

I am using a preloader to load external swf and accessing its functions/ variables, but after external swf loaded my movieclip (Which contains buttons to access external swf) is staying behind the loaded swf, now I want that movieclip to stay on top of the loaded external swf.

Code using for loader:

```
loadMovieNum("discocubes.swf", 0);

hackMenu.dragBar.onPress = function(){
    startDrag(hackMenu);
}
hackMenu.dragBar.onRelease = function(){
    stopDrag();
}

hackMenu.livesHackBtn.onRelease = function(){
    if (_root.n_Level >= _root.o_CubeTutorial.length || _root.s_GameStyle == "survival")
       {
            _root.f_ShowMessage("Level Up!");
       }// end if
    _root.f_StartGame(_root.s_GameMode, _root.n_Level + 1, _root.s_GameStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hackMenu.swapDepths(_root.getNextHighestDepth());
```

Comment: where we have to use this, I tried after loadmovie but its not working

Comment: @user1209015 try this: `hackMenu.swapDepths(999);`

Comment: thanks for your reply after which statement I have to use this. I tried <code>hackMenu.swapDepths(999);</code> after loadmovie still its not working, here is the link for the .fla and .swf <code>http://www.mediafire.com/?9zv1rhxvc62ax5m</code> pls check this and help